# Keywords cannot be edited when the hover prompt box is in focus

Tags: visual-studio-code, hover

When the mouse moves over the keyword, a hover prompt box pops up, which is convenient
If I want to modify the word in the keyword, when the left mouse click across the word, the hover box will pop up and be focused, at this time I can no longer edit the keyword

Trigger process: press the left mouse button, move and select the word, stop moving the mouse for 1 second, move the mouse slightly again, and release the mouse. The hover prompt is now in focus

[gif of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9f0B.gif)

example：

```
namespace foo{
  void foo_bar_function(); 
}
```

I want to change 'bar' to 'baz', and when I mouse over slowly, it triggers a problem

The relevant Settings are not found in the Settings

```
Version: 1.84.2 (user setup)
Commit: 1a5daa3a0231a0fbba4f14db7ec463cf99d7768e
Date: 2023-11-09T10:51:52.184Z
Electron: 25.9.2
ElectronBuildId: 24603566
Chromium: 114.0.5735.289
Node.js: 18.15.0
V8: 11.4.183.29-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22621
```

Comment: Welcome! "move the mouse again" move to where? also, a gif or video might be helpful just to make sure we are understanding your steps right. Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**.